# Jaspersoft Studio: How to use Collection of Java Beans in data adapter

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Docs are outdated and not helpful anyway. I use the dialog to add the class and and the static method, as well as the path to the .jar file holding the relevant classes.

When I hit test connection I get an error saying it cannot find the class ....

[image]

Yes the jar file is at that path. Do I need to further at that path somewhere else in the project properties or something??

Here's a [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/working-collection-javabeans-data-adapter) to the part of the docs that is supposed to describe this process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem in full name of class - probably the package is missing in your case.

### Sample

Here is the sample how it works in *Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1* (*JSS*).

#### Java code

Bean Order:

```
package ru.alex;

public class Order {

    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private Product product;

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Order(double price, int quantity, Product product) {
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Bean *Product*:

```
package ru.alex;

public class Product {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the factory for getting *Collection* of *Order* objects with static method:

```
package ru.alex;

import java.util.*;

public class OrderFactory {

    public static Collection<Order> getOrders() {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(new Order(8.0, 2, new Product("apples")));
        orders.add(new Order(2.5, 10, new Product("oranges")));
        return orders;
    }
}
```

All classes are at *ru.alex* package.

#### Data adapter settings

The settings of *Collection of JavaBeans* type data adapter in *JSS*:

[image: Adapter Settings]

This data adapter was created with help of wizard:

[image: Type of adapter]

I did not add the *beans.jar* to the project's *Java Build Path* in *JSS* and everything (adapter) works ok. It can be checked by pressing of *Test* button.

The checkbox *Use field description* does not play any role in this game.

I used the full class name: `ru.alex.OrderFactory` in settings.

And now this adapter can be used in report.

#### Creating report's template

Since the adapter is ready we can use it.

At *Dataset and Query Dailog* we can ignore message that `class not found by ....` and manually add the fields after setting the class name.

[image: Dataset and Quqery dialog]

The report will be something like this:

```
<jasperReport ...>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JavaBeanCollection - orders"/>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
```

If we add the jar with our beans to the IDE build path, like this:

[image: The libs path]

the behaviour will be changed. The list of fields will be appear automatically after typing the class name at *Dataset and Query Dailog*:

[image: Dataset and Query Dailog, auto filling]

**After adding second jar we can got the *ClassCastException* trouble. Only single *jar* with same classes should be added to classpath (*JSS*). Please look at the bottom of a post to find more information.**

### Templates

If we want to show only field from *Order* class we can use only the *Dataset and Query Dailog* to construct fields list.

The *jrxml* for showing prices & quantities of orders will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report with Bean" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JavaBeanCollection - orders"/>
    <field name="product" class="ru.alex.Product">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quantity]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

If we want to show, for example the product name we need to add the new field:

```
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product.name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

In this case the template be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report with Bean" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JavaBeanCollection - orders"/>
    <field name="product" class="ru.alex.Product">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quantity]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product.name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

---

**Beware!** We can face the issue described at [Why do I get error when trying to retrive bean from my data adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44047133/876298) post. We should stay only one *jar* with *Bean* classes. For example, *jar* at *Java Build Path*.

The full desciption is at referenced post.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed sample. Please remember to generate the JAR file with a lower Java version (eg. 1.8), other way the data adapter test hangs on and it's not going to work at all.