# Jasper Studio JRE build path specifies execution environment error

Tags: java, eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

I am new to Jasper Studio. I have created a data source using java beans collection following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902602/jaspersoft-studio-how-to-use-collection-of-java-beans-in-data-adapter) but I am getting this error which I think it causes my report not to fill the report with the collections of my bean.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Build path specifies execution
> environment JavaSE-1.6. There are no JREs installed in the workspace
> that are strictly compatible with this environment.   MyReports       Build
> path  JRE System Library Problem

I have tried even changing the runtime environment on the build path to another version but I am still getting the same error. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4) also but it doesn't solve my problem. I am using Jasper Studio 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jasper studio 6.1.0 had classpath problems. I downloaded jasper studio version 6.4.3 and it is working fine. It has been enhanced with features.